# Powershell script to comb event log on remote server(very new to powershell)

Tags: powershell, events, smtp, credentials

```
    $Tempdate=(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
$date= Get-Date $Tempdate -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" 
$cred = Get-Credential
$computer = "192.168.000.00"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {

$EventError = get-eventlog -logname system | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 7040} | Select-Object -Property Source, EventID, InstanceId, Message} -Credential $cred

if ($EventError.EntryType -eq "7040")
{

Send-MailMessage -To “[Redacted]@[Redacted].com” -From “[Redacted]@[Redacted].com”  -Subject “Event 7040 Triggered, review event logs.” -Body “A[Redacted]ir has had event 7040 triggered” -Credential (Get-Credential) -SmtpServer “mail.[Redacted]mail.com” -Port 587
}
```

Hello and Good morning!
I'm currently working on a script to comb and send an email if a specific event log entry is found, This is where i'm currently stuck... It runs but does nothing, even changing the Event-ID -EQ to a known entry in the past 24 hours, i no longer have issues with winRM, nor errors with smtp server, just nothing happens, it runs for about 30 seconds then says completed with no email returned.
Thanks in advance for your help, like i said, i am very new to powershell :)

-Devin

Comment: To make sure an entry is actually found, try replacing email-sending with something else temporarily. Tackle one issue at a time to isolate the problem step-by-step.

Comment: [1] you never seem to assign the output of the `Invoke-Command` call to anything at all. ///// [2] you never seem to output anything from the I-C scriptblock. ///// [3] given the 2 items above, _where is `$EventError.EntryType` supposed to come from? [*grin*]

Comment: as an aside, if you organize your indentation to make each stage clear, then the fact that you have scope problems would be a bit more apparent. [*grin*]